# Design criteria and out of the box thinking for the interior of a non humanoid alien ship

Tags: shipbuilding, ergonomics, aesthetics

I am trying to design the interiors of spaceships for non humanoid aliens and I am wondering if there is an overall formula that can aid in these designs.

I have tried asking on other sites or branches of stack exchange about examples of this in sci fi, where the design is unique and fitting to the aliens design (without being just a shape change of a human design) or designs which are very alien and not recognisable as a human at all. The problem is not having decent answers on other sites or the question being off topic as it is list based on Stackexchange.

I am wondering what are the key points to a design which no matter the aliens body design will be necessary, such as ergonomic features fitting to its body shape, even though this means I could fall into the path I don't want which is basically recreating human designs but changing it partially to fit the alien body shape, it is a start to which I can then play around with and make it seem as alien as possible.

What are the necessary points to consider when designing the interior of a non humanoid alien ship and how can these features be designed outside of intuitive human design forms.

Comment: Like you don't buy the same items for your dog, your cat, your parrot or your colony of ants, it all depends on the alien type. Blind alien? No need for screen. But going further, vegetable alien? No need for cooking areas at all, only water and constant light is needed. It's impossible to have an overall approach if we don't know what your alien is, more so if you don't like taking inspiration from humans. That's most likely why you won't get any "decent" answer, and the reason I vote to close (needs details)

Comment: This seems like a very subjective question.  Every worldbuilder is going to have a different idea of what the "necessary points" are when designing the interior of a spaceship. Just look at all the different spaceship interiors that exist in fiction when considering just the human spaceships. What makes you think that the answer will be any less broad when you remove the "useful to humans" requirement from the designs.

Comment: I am not as well versed as probably most on here about examples in sci fi but all that I have seen are very similar to current ship or plane designs but with a few aesthetic changes. I have some biological aliens designed similar to earth creatures: octopus, spider etc so this narrows the scope to a recognisable body type and its needs but that doesn't mean they would have similar designs to us but it also doesnt mean that they are not ergonomics humans could use.

Comment: * not ergonomics that humans could not use or understand.

Comment: @JarredJones That's a little better knowing that the source of inspiration is from Earth (and most likely animals), but there are hundreds if not thousands of animal categories ^^'. I'll take your two example animals and make them aliens : Octopi would love to have a water-pressurised environment, while spiders don't. Spiders could have very small ships, and the need to have an up and down is mostly negated by their ability to climb walls. With these two you can see how widely different the approach is, with sooo few in common. And that's not talking about multi-species ships :p.

Answer (score 2):

**Rooms**

How social is your species? If they live in huge groups they need huge rooms to fit them all. If they are solitary they need small rooms so they can get privacy.

If they live on rolling plains they might want larger rooms and higher ceilings. If they live in dense vegetation they want smaller rooms.

**Sleeping**

Again depending on sociality they will either sleep alone or in one big pile. This will effect how private quarters work.

**Diet**

Is there a "mess hall" like in Star Trek? Can these people eat their meals in short order? Or do they need to carry around 10kg of leaves in a pouch that they munch on through the day.

**Control Panels**

In general for any input device. Should be designed for the alien anatomy.

**Viewscreens**

In general for any output device. Should be designed for the alien senses.

**Corridors**

Burrowing species might want diagonal corridors. Territorial animals might want single-file corridors so you are never opposed by someone going the wrong way. This leads to fights.

**Atmosphere**

Is it full of air or water or vacuum? Do they generate gravity? Swimming creatures might prefer to be zero gravity.

**Surfaces**

Climbing or flying creatures will have different rooms than walking creatures. For example they might be tall with many platforms.

Answer (score 0):

**Borrow from ants.**

[image: leafcutter ant]

https://www.sciencefocus.com/nature/leaf-cutter-ants-fungi/

Here is a leafcutter ant colony.  It is a grown thing, made of fungus.  It is radically different from human architecture.  Also nifty is the omnidirectional aspect which is alien to all human architecture but makes sense for ants, and also in zero gravity.

A similar fractilliform (is that a word) ant structure is a fire ant colony.  There is a vogue for metal castings of these.  I could see this scaled up as a scifi spaceship.

[image: fire ant aluminum nest casting]

https://www.theverge.com/2013/12/13/5207824/anthill-art-molten-aluminum